# Approximate rhythm of speech

Tags: matlab

Is there any way or function in Matlab to approximate the rhythm of speech? How can it be done? If not, what should I use to do that?

Comment: If you could tell us what the digital characteristics of the rhythm of speed might be, we might be able to help you write Matlab code to perform computations for your needs.  It seems to me that your first problem is to make this characterisation digital, and that that is not a programming question and this question is, therefore, off-topic for SO.  Once you have an outline of the code you are looking for, ask another question.

Comment: Sorry for that mark but i am stucked in this - i didn't find any code or help yet :( for finding the rhythm of speech

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705632/using-nuance-speechkit-to-track-rate-of-speech

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018592/measuring-rate-of-speech-in-realtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a DSP-related question. You should first read up on speech rate literature. http://scholar.google.es/scholar?q=speech+rate+estimation