# How to track rate of speech

Tags: ios, iphone, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

I am developing an iPhone app that tracks rate of speech, and hoping to use Nuance Speechkit (https://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/Basics.html)

Is there a way to track rate of speech (e.g., updating WPM every few seconds) with the framework? Right now it seems to just do speech-to-text at the end of a long utterance, as opposed to every word or so (i.e., return partial results).

Answer (score 0):

There are easier ways, for example you can use CMUSphinx with phonetic recognizer to recognize just phonemes instead of words. It would work locally on the device and will be very fast. From the rate of phones you can calculate the rate of words with pretty high accuracy.