# measuring rate of speech in realtime

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm looking for a quick and simple way to measure the rate at which I am speaking in real time. Course grained approaches or approximations are sufficient. The idea is to write a simple app/widget that at least tells you to speed up or slow down while speaking. Measuring things like pitch and volume might also be nice.

I assume this can be done simply with a variety of speech recognition libraries, but I am familiar with none of them and quick glances at the documentation do not give a simple answer or even a good notion of which library to look at in more depth.

Ideally the library would have a python interface, but anything that can run on linux/osx/android would suffice. iOS is not viable.  Usability of the library/examples is more important than performance.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33705632/how-to-track-rate-of-speech

Answer (score 0):

Efficient speech rate detection can be done without speech recognition because speech recognition requires a lot of computation. The algorithm is described in

[Dagen Wang and Shrikanth S. Narayanan. Robust speech rate estimation for spontaneous speech.](http://sail.usc.edu/publications/files/WangTASLP2007%5B2%5D.pdf)

[Ali Ziaei, Abhijeet Sangwan, John H. L. Hansen. A Speech System for Estimating Daily Word Counts](http://www.isca-speech.org/archive/archive_papers/interspeech_2014/i14_0880.pdf)

and uses peak detector for very fast estimation of the word counts.

There is no open source implementation though, but it is worth to implement it yourself.